# About the Mueller's (summation) formula?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, finite-differences, discrete-calculus

Let $f$ be a real function with $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=0$.
(1) What is the necessary conditions for  the Mueller's formula:

$$
\sum_{x}f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(f(n)-f(n+x))+C ?
$$
(2) What is $C$?

(3) Any references about it, Euler–Maclaurin formula and  Antidifferences of special functions (e.g., eponential, logarithm, trigonometric, etc.)?

Comment: There are incoherent indexes in your post.

Comment: You seem to be referring to the Wikipedia article: [Indefinite sum: Mueller formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_sum#Mueller.27s_formula). The series is defined in this article [How to add a non-integer number of terms, and how to produce unusual infinite summations](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042704003851).